# combination of list elements of a list

Tags: python, list

I want the following output: [[1,2,1,2],[1,2,3,4],[3,4,1,2],[3,4,3,4]] but my code does not work out properly.

```
flag_2=[[1,2],[3,4]]

for i in flag_2:
        icopy = copy.copy(i)
        print "icopy",icopy
        for j in flag_2:
             temp4=[]
             jcopy = copy.copy(j)
             print "jcopy",jcopy
             temp4=copy.copy(list_extend(icopy,jcopy))
             print temp4
             temp4=[]
             print temp4
```

Answer (score 4):

Use itertools' `product` to get the combinations you need and `chain` to flatten the result:

```
from itertools import product,chain

[list(chain.from_iterable(c)) for c in product(flag_2,repeat=2)]
Out[7]: [[1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Or `[x for c in product(flag_2,repeat=2) for x in c]`

Comment: @roippi: why do you need the surrounding `[]`?

Comment: @wap26 it's a list comprehension.  That's the syntax.

Comment: @roippi: yes, obviously. I misread your answer.